# mount_smbfs returns error when using password with special character

Tags: macos, passwords, mount

I use macos and trying to mount my network drive :

```
mount_smbfs //user:passwd@SERVER /mount/point
```

for example for user = 'John' and password = 'test'

```
mount_smbfs //John:test@192.168.1.100/shared_folder /Users/John/Desktop
```

This will works just fine.

But if i edit John's password to include special character in it, for  example adding '?' --> 'test?' . If i invoke the same command again :

```
mount_smbfs //John:test?@192.168.1.100/shared_folder /Users/John/Desktop
```

It will give me error :
**no matches found: //John:test?@192.168.1.20/CLAYNET**

Any idea how to pass the password which contains special character ( like '?' in this example).

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters have meaning to the command shell. When running a command that requires a special character you must use single quotes.

```
mount_smbfs '//John:test?@192.168.1.100/shared_folder' /Users/John/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `mount_smbfs` will fail even when special characters are escaped in the shell, as James suggested.  In this case, special characters fed into `mount_smbfs` have to be URL encoded, as it relies on characters such as `;`, `:` and `@` to separate arguments:

```
mount_smbfs //John:test%3F@192.168.1.100/shared_folder /Users/John/Desktop
```

Note that this is true not just for special characters in the password, but also special characters in the share name, username, or even DNS name.

Alternatively, you can leave off the password entirely, and `mount_smbfs` will prompt for it:

```
mount_smbfs //John@192.168.1.100/shared_folder /Users/John/Desktop
```

This is considered more secure, as your plaintext password won't be stored in your shell history.